# Wordpress rewrite url for my plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, routes

How can make a custom url for my first wordpresss plugin. I don't know how to run my code. Something went wrong with this when i enter '/hom-nay' that show 404 page.

```
add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule('hom-nay', "today.php", 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like

```
add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule('^hom-nay$', "today.php", 'top');
});
```

OR setting it to some function or in index.php with some page? I think it is trying to find "today.php" in the base URL so it might be the problem instead of finding in you plugin directory.

Here is a great reference and may be the solution that you need:
http://www.ringabell.org/en/appeller-un-fichier-de-template-custom-avec-une-rewrite-rule-dans-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you now i try [code]
add_action('init', function () {
    //add_rewrite_rule('^hom-nay$', "today.php", 'top');
        add_rewrite_rule('hom-nay/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?plugins/hexagrams=$matches[1]', 'top');

//    flush_rewrite_rules();
});
echo'123';exit();[/code]
the url work pretty but still show 404 page.

Comment: is "today.php" in the root directory? or in plugin directory?

Comment: "today.php" in plugins directory

Comment: That is why, you see most of the examples: the rewrite is for "index.php?plugins/hexagrams=$matches[1]" or something like this. You need make a reference to index.php to load that today.php.
`add_rewrite_rule('^hom-nay$', "index.php?p=1", 'top');`
This will reference URL to post id 1, similarly you need to reference with the index.php

Comment: Yes, I understand. Rewrite doesn't work the way you want, it looks for the reference to root directory and not the plugin directory. You must make a index.php reference to your plugin and add rewrite with that reference.

Comment: Can u tell me how to reference